# Is there a way to represent multi-dimensional arrays in lambda calculus?

Tags: arrays, lambda-calculus

I am currently studying lambda calculus, and would like to represent an array that accepts multiple dimensions. I still haven't figured out how to implement uni-dimensional arrays though.

I have found an interesting article on [how to represent lists in lambda-calculus](https://sookocheff.com/post/fp/representing-pairs-and-lists-in-lambda-calculus/), but nothing for arrays. I have been unsuccessfully trying to extend the definition of lists into that of arrays.

I appreciate any help provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two important properties of the pure lambda calculus are that (1) it is untyped, and (2) it is not very precise about efficiently representing data structures. There are extensions to the lambda calculus which fix these problems, but if you are interested in representing data structures directly in the lambda calculus, you have to accept that they will not have a notion of type and will not necessarily represented very efficiently.

As a result of these properties: **in the lambda calculus, there is no fundamental difference between a list and an array.** That is, you can represent an array *as* a list. This gives you exactly the properties you need: the array should support accessing elements by index, and it should support initialization, and it should support iterating over elements. Since lists support all these features, they can be used as arrays. Now you may object that this is not the kind of implementation of arrays you are expecting, because it *also* supports other operations including concatenation, and it is not necessarily efficient. But it is a perfectly valid implementation of arrays in the lambda calculus, and since we don't have types, we have no way of annotating the difference between the two; both lists and arrays are just lambda terms, which support certain operations.

Furthermore, you can represent a multidimensional array in the usual way as a single uni-dimensional array. For example, a 2D array with dimensions $m \times n$ is represented as a single array of length $mn$; and to access the element at $(i, j)$, we access the $(ni + j)$th element of the unidimensional array.